# Using watchers how to validate email in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
watch: {

    email(value) {
      this.email = value;
      this.validateEmail(value);
    },
  },

  methods() {
    validateEmail() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      if (/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(this.email)) {
        this.errmsg.email = ''
      } else this.errmsg['email'] = 'Invalid Email Address';

    },
```

```html
<input class="input-mobile-email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" id="email" v-model="email" name="email" :maxlength="maxemail" @input="validateEmail" />

<button class="submit-button" data-toggle="modal" type="submit" value="Submit" data-target="#exampleModal" :class="isDisabled ? '' : 'selected'" :disabled="isDisabled">Submit</button>
```

Using watchers how to validate email address in Vuejs?  I am trying the functionality to disable the button until the user enters valid email.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to achieve that :

```
computed() {
  isEmailValid() {
    return '/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/'.test(this.email)
  }
}
```

and then replace your **isDisabled** by `isEmailValid`

Working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/u0c98kmL/

Comment: In the input do i need to write @input="isEmailValid" and then in isDisabled i called like ||   (!this.email || !this.isEmailValid)

is this right??

Comment: getting error as TypeError: "/^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/".test is not a function

Comment: You just have to use ```v-model="email"``` on the input, and not **@input**

Comment: And in  isDisabled: function () {

      return (this.mobile.length < 10) || (!this.nameChange.length) 
       ||   (!this.email  || this.isEmailValid);

Is this the right way to pass inside isDisabled?

Comment: I am sorry, i did not get exactly, if possible can u please give some working snippet.

Comment: I tried this but it is not validating https://jsfiddle.net/k69cr0sf/

Comment: Here's a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u0c98kmL/

Answer (score 0):

In your case (if we are talking only about email validation), will be much easier to create computed property for this, as Takachi said.
And you did not need any watchers for this case.

But if you need more validations, please, use some lib like https://vuelidate.js.org or just check how it is done.

Comment: I tried this but it is not validating  https://jsfiddle.net/k69cr0sf/

Comment: Just check it please https://jsfiddle.net/gbyo6den/7/